# magento add to cart button not work on mobile screen

Tags: magento

I have a problem on magento home page, on mobile screen.
when I click on add to cart, item not added to cart.(on product page or on laptop screen on home page there is no problem)

on home page on mobile screen the button code is:

```
<button type="button" title="Add to Cart" class="button btn-cart show-options btn-cart-mobile" data-id="3"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button>
```

but should be:

```
<button type="button" title="Add to Cart" class="button btn-cart btn-cart-mobile" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to Cart</span></span></button>
```

where I should be change this code?

Comment: is there any error in concol or log file it show?

Comment: just show undefined page.

Answer (score 0):

with a lot of search I found the solution:
we should change the product block life cache in home page to 1